# How can i delete a pointer to array in C++

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, delete-operator

I am wondering how can i use the delete operator if I want to delete an array initialized like this:

```
int (*my_ptr)[10] = new int[3][10];
```

This seems invalid:

```
delete[][]
```

Comment: `delete[][]` is invalid. Use `delete[]`. It will should call all destructors , as required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`new int[3][10]` is simply creation of a dynamic array whose elements are themselves arrays. This is deleted in the same way as all dynamic arrays: `delete[]`.

Comment: @asmmo That might be confusing since sub objects do not have static storage.

Answer (score 4):

`my_ptr` is an array of 3 elements. Each element is an `int[10]` type.

You call `delete[] my_ptr;` to delete those 3 elements.

Comment: It's actually an array of 3 arrays of 10 elements. I got this wrong too first. It's strange, but the dynamic part is in the middle of the element type.